# Create javascript project in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

How do you create javascript project in Netbeans?

There is no such language category.

Answer (score 8):

The JavaScript project type was removed because it's essentially superfluous.  Even in a non-JavaScript project, NetBeans will still recognize any JavaScript libraries that you add, and code completion should still work automatically.

**Reference:**  http://forums.netbeans.org/ptopic14084.html

Answer (score 6):

Can you simply create a PHP project for example and then delete everything related to PHP? ;)

You can simply leave your .js and any other files you need (.html?).

Comment: Yeah..feels so ugly to do like this :)

Comment: Yeah, you may feel a bit dirty afterwards, but it will wear off! ;-)

Comment: I don't like this solution, because I'm trying to do node.js projects nowadays, and they aren't related to PHP at all... the node.js plugins are sparse right now

Answer (score 3):

There is a [node js plugin](https://github.com/timboudreau/nb-nodejs) which has a javascript project type for that.

There is also the [adhoc project plugin](https://github.com/timboudreau/adhoc-projects) which will let you treat any folder as a project for purposes of opening files (no "run" support).

Answer (score 1):

Since 8.1 (?):

[image]

​​​

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can choose "Java Web" for the category and "Web Free-Form Application". I had to provide it with a dummy "build script", but that was the worst hack.